# Proper Campaign Tracking With Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, email, goal-tracking

Let's say I have a link in an email newsletter like so: `example.com&utm_medium=email&utm_source=pardot&utm_campaign=Autumn+Newsletter&utm_content=logo`

I am able to go into Google Analytics>Aquisition>Campaigns>All Campaigns and I'm able to see that my link has been clicked, but I only see the medium and source of "email" and "pardot", but nothing for campaign or content. Is this still supposed to be shown in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All those parameters are available as Primary or Secondary dimensions in your Standard reports. If you look at @inkovic's screenshot at the top, you see the header, "Primary Dimension", and then there's "Campaign". Similarly, you can search for the Content (it's called "Ad Content").

If you want, you can even create a Custom Report which shows you all your campaign parameters, like this:

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh, ok! "Ad content" threw me off, since this isn't technically an ad, but that works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Other > Acquisition > Source

[image]